Problems with rewriting the question of a post that has already been answered
My post Where is the verb in reduplication of adjectives "Noun + Adj + Adj + 的"? was originally confusing because I didn't understand some ideas and I asked too many things. Then, as some of the answers addressed some questions but I still had some other doubts, I posted a new question How "Noun + Adj + Adj + 的" (reduplication of adjectives) is grammatically equivalent to "Noun + (Adv of degree) + Adj"? which asked something very related and still was confusing.
Now, I finally pinpointed my confusions and thought about sorting all that mess. I rewrote the first answer with the precise question I wanted to ask (but was hidden between my original questions). However, now the answers don't exactly apply to the question. Also, I thought about deleting the second post as now has becomes useless and confusing, but I can't do it because people already answered it. So, for now I just closed it as a duplicate. How should I address this matter?

It depends how you intend to change it:

If the changes will make the answers obsolete, it's not really appropriate.  Such ever-changing questions are sometimes called chameleon questions and are frustrating to answerers who have already spent time answering a question only for it to change.

However, edits to polish the question that do not render existing answers obsolete are both fine and welcome.


I feel your edits to Where is the verb in reduplication of adjectives "Noun + Adj + Adj + 的"? are a significant improvement, although some of the answers quote the older version.  Perhaps the simplest solution is to add a comment to the post mentioning the edit and linking to the original version https://chinese.stackexchange.com/revisions/39997/1.  That way people aren't downvoting (etc.) answers which don't appear to address the question.
I did something similar here: For the HSK, what do I need to know about characters which appear differently?  In this question, I asked a question about variant characters only to find out I had a problem with my computer's font.

Thank you for the answer. So how should I address the second post? Is signaling it as duplicated enough? I feel though it would be better to just delete it, as it does not bring anything new now but maybe just some confusion.

I would have just accepted the most useful answer and moved on.  But closing it as a duplicate works too.  In any case, the system won't let you delete a question with upvoted answers.
